# If i install Cisco any connect inside my iPhone, can our system admin access my iPhone without my knowledge

Tags: security, iphone

I work for a company, and i need to access some internal sites inside my iPhone. so i got the instruction from our network team to install Cisco any-connect to my iPhone and connect to our network. but my question is, since this is my personal mobile device, so if i am connected to our network using Cisco any-connect, can our system admins or network admins access my iPhone content while i am connected through Cisco any-connect?

Thanks

Comment: What level of access is being talked about? If someone can see what I browse, I will call it access too!

Comment: @ankiiiiiii thanks for the reply. i think knowing what i am browsing during my connection with CISCO any-connect is understandable, as i will be connected to the company network,, but my concern if someone will be able to access my personal photos or messages inside my phone, without my notice... for example when i am connected to my PC which is joined to the company domain, inside our company using an Ethernet cable, i know that the PC can be accessed by our IT admin, and they backup our C drive, bu not sure if they can do the same to my personal iPhone, or the situation will be different?

Answer (score 2):

Cisco anyconnect is nothing more than a VPN app that is designed to connect back to your work network securely.

They likely have resources on the Intranet that are not available to the outside world and the VPN will put you onto that network using that Cisco VPN software.

Generally speaking this will not give network administrators (your IT dept.) access to your phone. VPN software is designed to give *you* access to *their* systems. So unless your IT people have inserted a trojan into Cisco's VPN software (doubtful in the extreme) you are safe from your IT department gaining access to your personal device using that software.

Comment: thanks for the reply . yes i need to connect to the VPN to be able to accessed our internal sites, actually i need to test an application using a mobile app, and the mobile app will be accessing our internal systems which are not exposed to the internet. so without the VPN i can not access our internal systems from my mobile... also i do not think that someone can install a trojan inside the VPN software, as i will install the CISCO any-connect from apple store, my concern if they can install a trojan software inside the back-end. or this is an extreme case as well?

Comment: It's possible, but if you have a fully up to date iPhone that is generally a long shot. Also if you don't trust your company to not hack your personal devices perhaps its time to find another company. Just sayin'...